# Trouble with fade in on hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css, fade, onhover

I'm trying to create a simple ***fade in on hover*** effect.

The black bars with the text should be invisible by default and slowly fade in once you hover over the image.

I've searched and tried a few different methods, but haven't quite made it work yet.

One of the methods was [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/ynUKx/1/), which is very simple and should have worked, but for some reason it didn't...

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

This is my current situation:

HTML:

```
<div id="panel4" class="panels" style="cursor: move; z-index: 48">
<div class="title"><span>&nbsp;TITLE | THIS IS THE TITLE</span></div>
<div id="picture4"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fbEGCcY.png"></div>
<div class="footer"><span>FOOTER | THIS IS THE FOOTER&nbsp;</span></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.panels {
position: absolute;
}

#panel4 {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

#picture4 {
width: 480px;
height: 360px;
}

.title {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
color: #fff;
background: #000;
font-family: Monaco;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: left;
line-height: 20px;
position: absolute;
}

.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
color: #fff;
background: #000;
font-family: Monaco;
font-size: 10px;
font-weight: normal;
text-align: right;
line-height: 20px;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
}

span {
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
line-height: normal;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8D25H/)

Comment: For this case, JavaScript is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/8D25H/5/

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#picture4").hover(function(){
$(this).parent().children(".title, .footer").fadeToggle(800);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: It does work, but there's a glitch. When you hover over the black bars it fades in 'n' out continually... that shouldn't happen, the image is behind the black bars, so they should stay on all the time. Do you know why that happens and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr853/.  I've also cleaned up some of your code.

HTML:

```
<div class = "container">
    <header>TITLE | THIS IS THE TITLE</header>
    <footer>FOOTER | THIS IS THE FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*, :before, :after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
    height: 360px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/fbEGCcY.png)
                no-repeat;
                100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container > header, 
.container > footer {
    font: normal 10px/2 Monaco, Sans-Serif;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear;

}

.container > footer {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.container:hover > header,
.container:hover > footer {
    opacity: 1;
}
```